# Javascript/jquery create array from elements with same rel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you create an array with from a set of elements with same rel?

Eg:

```
<a rel='array' id='2' url='aa'></a>
<a rel='array' id='5' url='bb'></a>
<a rel='array' id='8' url='cc'></a>
```

Array:

```
[2] > aa
[5] > bb
[8] > cc
```

I put each URL as value just to use something. But having the IDs ordered should be enough.

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you use jQuery or anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
    let current = anchors[i];

    if(current.getAttribute('rel') == 'array') {
        // arr.push(current.getAttribute('url'));
        arr.push({ 'id' : current.id, 'url' : current.getAttribute('url') });
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ScSH/

---

Or, more succinctly:

```
const anchors = [...document.getElementsByTagName('a')];
const arrs = anchors.filter(x => x.getAttribute('rel') === 'array')
    .map(x => { return { 'id': x.id, 'url': x.getAttribute('url') } });
```

Answer (score 2):

Not enough jquery!

```
var arr = [];
$('a[rel="array"]').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).attr('url'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy if you're using jquery:

```
var arr = [];
$('a[rel="array"]').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).attr('url'));
});
```

​
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAAUu/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemArray = [];
$("a[rel='array']").each(function() { itemArray.push($(this).attr("url") });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var a = {};

$('#wrap a').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('rel') === "array") {
        a[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).attr('url');
    }
});​​
```

An array won't cut it, you need an object. Here live: http://jsfiddle.net/martincanaval/rAPkL/

Comment: same idea applies without using Jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/martincanaval/3GAYN/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = [];
$('a[rel="array"]').each(function() {
    elements[this.id] = $(this).attr('url');
});
```

Note that this creates a sparse array with only the index values specified by the element ids, which doesn't make much sense to me, but that's what you asked for. It *really* doesn't make sense if any of the ids can be non-numeric - if so you should use an object rather than an array, i.e.:

```
var elements = {};
```

*"I put each URL as value just to use something. But having the IDs ordered should be enough."*

If your intention is to get an array of the ids then you can do this:

```
var elementIds = [];
$('a[rel="array"]').each(function() {
    elementIds.push(this.id);
});
```

That would create the array `['2', '5', '8']` where the ids will be in the order that they appear within your source html.

However, just saying `$('a[rel="array"]')` gives you a jQuery object that is an array-like structure holding all the matching elements - that's why we can iterate over each of the elements using the `.each()` method. So it's possible that whatever you're really trying to do can be done directly with jQuery rather than setting up your own array.